# Cell Phone Purse w/ Touch Screen Easy Access

Tags: touchscreen

Hi I want to make Cell Phone Purse w/ Touch Screen Easy Access in mass production . My question, what is the quality of plastic which used window in front of cellphone which is touch screen . Thanks

Comment: Why don't you try various things?  I've found that a poly sandwich bag usually doesn't impede function much, though it's not a great surface if ones finger is at all damp.  Chances are whatever factory you work with may already know what a suitable substance is...

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation . I'll try and see if it gives result like DISPLOX made in Portugal